# How to sum rows for different row names

Tags: r, sum

I have a dataset subset for a site 'Tolna' with column named 'Year' containing years from 1962 to 2009. I then have 48 columns named all differently and I want to sum all off them into one and name it Species amount. SO basically I want to count all the row numbers and place it next to the each year.

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfhb2.jpg)

Comment: Sample data, as has been requested before. Similar to a previous question, please post the output from `dput(Tolnadf[1:10,1:10])`.

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, if I've understood properly :)

```
# rowsums on all columns except Site & Year, ignoring NA's if they exist, and then passing in to the Species column the output
Tolnadf$Species <- rowSums(Tolnadf[, !names(Tolnadf) %in% c("Site", "Year")], na.rm=TRUE)
Tolnadf[, c("Site", "Year", "Species")]
```